# Why is the Postman Code Generator Link missing after upgrade?

Tags: api, postman

I upgraded to Postman v8.0.4 and after the upgrade, the code generator link is missing.
Does anyone know why this link is missing in my instance of Postman?
Is there some setup I am supposed to do after the upgrade?

[image: Missing Code Generator Link]

Answer (score 4):

With Postman v8, the code generation feature has moved to the context bar on the right of the screen. This is available for both requests (eg. All Collections) and examples (eg. Valid Response).

[image: Code generation in context bar]